# what to do if I don't have page specific API call?

Tags: javascript, rest, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm using Polymer js,suppose if I have page A,B,C and I request a signin API call in page A and I need that response in page B and C till user signout. so when I get response I store response in a JS local variable and I'll bind that variable to page B and C with data binding and pass values,it works good until I refresh the page B or C.When I refresh page B or C all my local variables are destroyed,page B and C are depending on page A data and even I cant store entire response in localstorage since anyone can edit.What is the solution for this type of problem i.e when we don't have a page specific API?How keep API response data till end?

Answer (score 0):

you could make that signIn Api again if you don't find that local variable you are looking for and then once you get response store it again in memory.

For signIn API to work you could store the data which was passed in the first place. and have it pass again in subsequent calls..

Comment: but each time when I sign in I get a unique session Id and I can't call that API mant times